# Android SDK: NSDictionary dictionary with objectsForKeys Equivalent

Tags: java, android

I have the following objective-c code

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:names forKeys:dates];
```

The names and dates are NSMutableArrays

What is the java equivalent of this code?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know objective-c but I would have thought that the equivalent of a Dictionary is a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html), for example a HashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the dates array elements are Long (Java date) and the names array elements are String.

```
Map<Long, String> dictionary = new HashMap<Long, String>();
for (int idx = 0; i < dates.length; ++idx) {
    dictionary.put(dates[idx], names[idx]);
}
```

Note that HashMap is not immutable like NSDictionary. If this is not acceptable use:

```
Collections.unmodifiableMap(dictionary);
```

Comment: the equivalent is Map<Object,Object>